# Below code in laravel send seller(without Auth) mail not working

Tags: laravel

Below code in laravel send seller(without Auth) mail not working.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = null;
    if(!Auth::check()){
        if(User::where('email', $request->email)->first() != null){
            flash(__('Email already exists!'))->error();
            return back();
        }
        if($request->password == $request->password_confirmation){
            $user = new User;
            $user->name = $request->name;
            $user->email = $request->email;
            $user->user_type = "seller";
            $user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
            $user->save();
        }

        else{
            flash(__('Sorry! Password did not match.'))->error();
            return back();
        }
    }
    else{
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user->customer != null){
            $user->customer->delete();
        }
        $user->user_type = "seller";
        $user->save();
    }

    if(BusinessSetting::where('type', 'email_verification')->first()->value != 1){
        $user->email_verified_at = date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
        $user->save();
    }

    $seller = new Seller;
    $seller->user_id = $user->id;
    $seller->save();

    if(Shop::where('user_id', $user->id)->first() == null){
        $shop = new Shop;
        $shop->user_id = $user->id;
        $shop->name = $request->name;
        $shop->address = $request->address;
        $shop->slug = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $request->name).'-'.$shop->id;

        if($shop->save()){

            flash(__('Your Shop has been created successfully!'))->success();
            return redirect()->route('shops.index');
        }
        else{
            $seller->delete();
            $user->user_type == 'customer';
            $user->save();
        }
    }

    flash(__('Sorry! Something went wrong.'))->error();
    return back();
}
```

Comment: Please format your code and please use less lines of code exactly where the problem is if you want help here

Comment: Please expand on what you mean by 'not working'. What happened vs what you expected to happen?

Comment: Are you trying to send an email?

Comment: yes send an email

Comment: What type of email would you like to send?
Who are you sending email to, the newly created user?

Comment: Yes,newly created user.Which is as a Seller.